# Auto Start Systemd Service

Tags: systemd, services

I have recently installed FreeFileSync on a my PC and managed to to getting the RealTimeSync working perfectly fine. All that is left to do is automatically call the script at start up. Initially, I used Cron with the @reboot parameter but that did not work out. So I decided to use systemd instead. I have created a user service file called sync.service which I have enabled and works perfectly fine when manually called via the systemctl --user start sync_1 command. However, it encounters errors on startup. Could anybody please? I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
ExecStart=/home/user/Desktop/sync.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Below is the error I encounter when I check the status of the systemd file after startup.

***sync_1.service Loaded: loaded (/etc/xdg/systemd/user/sync_1.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-06-14 21:19:19 BST; 47s ago Process: 1859 ExecStart=/home/user/Desktop/sync.sh (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION) Main PID: 1859 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)***

Comment: Please provide output of journalctl -xe command.

Comment: It's executing before you login and start the X server that `DISPLAY=:0` refers to.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for the response, how might I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: @KKPatel thank you for the response, any way I can attach the log here as a file?

Comment: You can edit question and put logs or you can use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and provide link in question.

Comment: @KKPatel thanks. This is what I pulled from my journalctl log,  not sure if there is anything there that helps? https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sQ89n4MyVy/

Comment: There is no details of sync.service in journlctl log.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.service` file contains `DISPLAY:=0`, whitch is a pointer to the X server's screen 0.

However, the X server is not started at system startup time, but only after you perform a GUI login.

So, when `/home/user/Desktop/sync.sh`, at  system startup time, tries to talk to the X server handling `DISPLAY:=0`, there's NO X server, and things blow up real good.

The startup of X server dependent tasks should be done by a `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.config/autostart/`. Read `man desktop-file-edit  desktop-file-validate`. Find examples with `locate .desktop`. Read the "Desktop Entry specifacation" https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/